# Django Rest Framework "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "patient" does not exist"

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework in my project.
I have written tests:

```
class PatientTests(APITestCase):

    def test_create_patient(self):
        url = reverse('patient-list')
        data = {'firstname': 'ivan', 'lastname': 'ivanov'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(Patient.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Patient.objects.get().firstname, 'ivan')

    def test_get_patient(self):
        url = reverse('patient-detail', args=[1])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, {'firstname': 'ivan'})
```

models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    firstname = models.TextField()
    lastname = models.TextField()
    secondname = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "patient"
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):

        return ' '.join([
            self.firstname,
            self.lastname,
            ])
```

When I run the test I get the error: "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "patient" does not exist". As I understand, this error occurs if the table is not created in the test database. What must I do? Thanks

Comment: show us your models first

Comment: Try to migrate your table. Reffer [Django Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/)

Comment: I have managed = False setting in Meta class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly delete all the .pyc files from your project.Then run following commands one by one.

```
$ django-admin.py migrate auth
$ django-admin.py migrate contentypes
$ django-admin.py migrate sites
$ django-admin.py migrate YOUR_USER_APP
$ django-admin.py migrate
```

If this does not work then use makemigrations for all your apps one by one,like this:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations 
$ python manage.py migrate --fake
```

And make sure to delete all the files with .pyc extension.

And for this to work,Please remove **'managed = False'** from your code. The error is because there is no table named **"patient"** in your database.

Comment: If I'll delete 'managed = False' I can damage my real data base. The real database is already created and I don't want to spoil it. Can I test my code without 'managed = True'?

Comment: @regen what is your real database..?? The patient table is clearly not in your database,so 'managed = True' will only create new db table 'patient'.whats the harm in that??

Comment: @regen Change "managed = False" only in Meta class of Patient Model.

Comment: Real data base - production data base , whitch created by DBA. If I'll put 'managed = True', then if I make any changes in 'Patient' model and execute 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' my changes put to production data base. But your solution works well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To have models created for your tests, a common pattern I use, is to mark them as managed before tests execute.  To do this, you could create a [custom test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner) and overrride `setup_test_environment`:

```
class CustomRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_test_environment(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.db.models.loading import get_models
        self.unmanaged_models = [
            m for m in get_models() if not m._meta.managed
        ]

        for m in self.unmanaged_models:
            m._meta.managed = True
```

And then the test settings would [specify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#using-different-testing-frameworks) the module path to the test runner as a string:

`TEST_RUNNER = module.path.to.CustomRunner`